# Why Yehoshua's lineage

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa, yehoshua-joshua

In Shemos 33:11, the prophet Yehoshua is referred to as Yehoshua bin Nun.

> וְדִבֶּ֨ר יְהוָ֤ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁה֙ פָּנִ֣ים אֶל־פָּנִ֔ים כַּאֲשֶׁ֛ר יְדַבֵּ֥ר אִ֖ישׁ אֶל־רֵעֵ֑הוּ וְשָׁב֙ אֶל־הַֽמַּחֲנֶ֔ה וּמְשָׁ֨רְת֜וֹ יְהוֹשֻׁ֤עַ בִּן־נוּן֙ נַ֔עַר לֹ֥א יָמִ֖ישׁ מִתּ֥וֹךְ הָאֹֽהֶל׃ (ס)

Why is specifically Yehoshua (and Kalev Ben Yefunah) referred to with their father's (or grandfather's) name?
Why don't we say Moshe ben Amram? Or Aharon ben Amram?

Comment: Is this Purim Torah? When we are first introduced to Moshe and Aharon we are told their ancestry, but not each time from the hundreds. When Yehoshua comes up, it's not as a frequent character, so we are told his yichus. In the book of Yehoshua it isn't like that..

Comment: @mordechai We're first introduced to Yehoshua in Beshalach and his father isn't mentioned.  Nun is also not mentioned when Yehoshua shows up in Mishpatim or earlier in Ki Tisa.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Tale_of_Yehoshua_Bin_Nun%2C_Introduction.1?lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=en

Comment: See Numbers 13:16.